# надпись внутри блока не смещается так как должно быть на картинке

Tags: html, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.background{
 /* Style for "bg" */

width: 1370px;
height: 7170px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header{
 /* Style for "BG" */
width: 1370px;
height: 143px;
background-color: #f8f6f6;
}
.BOOSTFOLIA{
 /* Style for "BOOSTFOLIA" */
width: 170px;
height: 29px;
color: #696969;
font-family: "Big Noodle Titling";
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
/* Text style for "BOOSTFOLIA" */
letter-spacing: 4px;
margin: 61, 964, 53, 236;
}[![надпись внутри блока не смещается так как должно быть на картинке][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ueC.jpg
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>0001</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="background">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="BOOSTFOLIA">BOOSTFOLIA</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Может быть ширина блока не позволяет этого сделать? Мне кажется лучше сам текст обернуть в span например, и потом применять стили к этому span. Скопировав ваш код, у меня текст оказался длиннее чем ширина блока

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```css
.background{
 /* Style for "bg" */

width: 1370px;
height: 7170px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.header{
 /* Style for "BG" */
width: 1370px;
height: 143px;
background-color: #f8f6f6;
}
.BOOSTFOLIA{
 /* Style for "BOOSTFOLIA" */
width: 400px;
height: 29px;
color: #696969;
font-family: "Big Noodle Titling";
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
/* Text style for "BOOSTFOLIA" */
letter-spacing: 4px;
margin: 61, 964, 53, 236;
}[![надпись внутри блока не смещается так как должно быть на картинке][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ueC.jpg
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>0001</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="background">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="BOOSTFOLIA">BOOSTFOLIA</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```